# First catch of the day and streak bonuses

Tags: pokemon-go

Recently, Pokémon GO had an update that allows you to gain extra experience from your first catch of the day. Actually, Niantic stated this on the Pokémon Facebook page:

> You’ll earn bonuses for the first Pokémon catch and PokéStop visit each day. You’ll receive a larger bonus when you do this seven days in a row.

What are these bonuses?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on [this website](http://heavy.com/games/2016/11/what-are-pokemon-go-daily-bonus-additional-items-how-much-xp-stardust-update-incubator-incense-chart-table-list-pokemongo/), the rewards are as follows:

```
    Action      |         Frequency      |        Reward
Catch Pokemon   |   First time a day     |  500 XP and 600 Stardust
Catch Pokemon   |   7th consecutive day  |  2,000 XP and 2,400 Stardust
Spin Pokestop   |   First time a day     |  500 XP and “additional items”
Spin Pokestop   |   7th consecutive day  |  2,000 XP and more “additional items”
```

It should be noted that the 7th consecutive day bonus is called a 'Streak Bonus' and is in addition to the First time a day bonus. See below for a screencapture of a streak bonus that includes the first catch bonus.

[image]

It should be noted also that the 7th consecutive spin gives more items and [according to an official PokemonGo update on March 21st](http://pokemongolive.com/en/post/ver-update-032117), a guaranteed Evolution item.

Comment: http://pokemongolive.com/en/post/daily-bonus/
This website also has the same details about the bonuses and states that it resets at 12 AM local time

Comment: What happens on the 8th day?  Does it start over at 500 XP, or continue at 2000?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it resets at 500 XP (ie first day)

Comment: On iOS, didn't get the bonus today. Doesn't look like it resets at midnight

Comment: @mjr Seeing as the Hallowe'en event started/stopped at UTC midnight, your observation probably means this feature follows UTC too.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm not so sure. I've been catching stuff at my desk all day, but I got another "First Catch of the Day" bonus as I sat down for my lunch break about an hour ago. That's like... 6:00 PM UTC.

Comment: Then maybe it's just bugged af, like any normal new Niantic feature

Comment: On Pokemon GO's Support for [Daily Bonuses](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/231973328-Daily-Bonuses), the 7-day bonuses are different than those listed in this answer.  But the page also states that bonuses reset at midnight, local time.  Maybe someone can experiment with their phone's time...

Comment: @Tester101 The count resets on the eight day, so can gain the "7th consecutive day" reward only once per week.

Comment: The explanation greatly improves the answer, thanks.

Comment: The answer needs to be improved because the 7th day spin now also includes a guaranteed evolution item.

Comment: @Montag451 Now updated with this information. There was a lot of conflicting information about whether or not the 7th spin grants an evolution item. It seems that it did and then it didn't and then it did again - according to http://pokemongoinformer.com/guaranteed-evolution-item-from-7-day-streak/